# BPy Image_Editor - remove Image completely problem

Tags: python, image, uv-image-editor

i have a big problem in the Image_Editor/UV to remove completely a Texture. her a screen:

[image: img remove problem]

I don't think I have to say anything more about that.

i hope anyone can me help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UI redraw issue.**

The issue you are seeing is UI related. The red is an indicator of this: warning that there is an issue, in this case showing the name of an image that has been removed.

If this is the case then issuing a tag redraw to the image editor will fix .

```
import bpy

img = bpy.data.images[0]
bpy.data.images.remove(img)

for a in bpy.context.screen.areas:
    if a.type == 'IMAGE_EDITOR':
        a.tag_redraw()
```